# How to turn float decimal values into integers in ruby

Tags: ruby, integer

How can one get the decimal values of a float and turn it into an integer in ruby?

Here is how far I got so far:

```
number = 12.55
decimal_length = number.to_s.split('.')[1].size #=> 2 
decimal = number.divmod(1)[1].round(decimal_length) #=> 0.55
```

Here how can I turn decimal into integer (55) in a way that it would work with any number as input?

Comment: Why 55? What if your value is 2.3? Is that 3 or 30? Is 2.909 converting to 90 or 909?

Comment: Nope. but as @mike said I was just doing extra work for my purpose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding? But you've got it you're just doing extra work.

```
number = 12.55
number.to_s.split('.')[1].to_i
#  => 55
```

Comment: Converting to a string and then splitting that into an array, pulling something out of an array and converting that back into an integer is completely nuts. `Float#to_i` does it on one step.

Comment: @tadman maybe you could provide an example for `Float#to_i`. When I do `Float(12.55).to_i` the result is `12`.

Comment: The problem here is `2.09` comes out with `9` as the answer. That would give the same results as `2.9`. Additionally, given how floating point numbers often render as `12.55000000190239012` this is going to produce some very crazy results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `number.to_i` to get the integer. To get the decimal value, you can do `number%1`

```
    number.to_i => 12
    number%1    => 0.5500000000000007
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Mike What about it isn't answered? I've asked for clarification on the question, the integer required is really ambiguous.

Comment: @tadman your comment for clarification was good but the original question did offer one example. Specifically that `12.55` should become `55`. This answer provides one line that changes `12.55` to `12`, and another that changes `12.55` to `0.5500000000000007`. Neither does what the question wanted.

Comment: @Mike It's completely unclear what the question wanted so I wouldn't pass judgement yet.

Comment: How to get the decimal values of a float(e.g. 12.55) and turn it into an integer? decimal values of the example float is 0.55 and its integer is 55. How is it completely unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Posting little late but I'm hoping it might be helpful

```
decimal_length = n.to_s.split(".").last.size # 2
decimal = (n.abs.modulo(1)*10**decimal_length).round # 55
```