# How to convert float values to integers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I run my test script it is giving the values as 0.2948e4 and 0.299e4 using `split`.

`count.to_s.split('.')[1].to_i` it is giving me the values as 2948 and 299 but the problem is for the 299 value. I executed my query manually and it is giving me 2990. The '0' is getting removed.

Also, trying the assertion am I doing it in the right way to validate? `target=source` should pass and `target!=source` should fail.

This is what I tried:

data_one =

```rb
def self.row_count(data_one)
    r = $dif_env.teradata.fetch "(#{data_one})"
    count = Hash[r.map{|key, value| [key, value]}]
    target = count.to_s.split('.')[1].to_i
    puts target
    source = count.to_s.split('.')[2].to_i
    puts source
    assert_equal 'target=source','target!=source'.nil?
end
```

The expected results should be `target = 2948` and `Source = 2990`.
The actual results are `target =2948` and `source = 299`.

I followed "[How to turn float decimal values into integers in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950059/how-to-turn-float-decimal-values-into-integers-in-ruby)".

Comment: "The '0' is getting removed" - it was never there.

Comment: But when i execute my query manually it is showing me the value as 2990. I m not sure why it was showing me 0.299e4. I was assuming may be after the '.' it is not considering the '0'.

Comment: Trailing zeroes in fractional part are not significant, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `count.to_s.split('.')[1].to_i` it is giving me the values as 2948 and 299 but the problem is for 299 value. I executed my query manually it is giving me 2990. The '0' is getting removed.

That is, mildly put, a wrong way to parse numbers in scientific notation. Try this instead:

```
'0.299e4'.to_f # => 2990.0
'0.299e4'.to_f.to_i # => 2990
```

Comment: I tried as you as said @sergio. I m getting 0> count.to_s.split('.')[2].to_f.to_i
=> 2990000

0> count.to_s.split('.')[2].to_f
=> 2990000.0

Comment: count= $dif_env.teradata.fetch "(#{data_one})"
puts count.to_a
If i m getting the values in this format
{:targetcount=>0.2948e4, :sourcecount=>0.299e4}
how can i convert them to to_f

Comment: @Phantom: it's not entirely obvious what are the types there (is it an array of strings with ruby-hash-representation inside? Is it an array of hashes? Something else?), but if you get can get to a _string_ `'0.299e4'`, then you can use my answer.

Comment: it's an array of hashes. What i am trying to do is, i wanted to do assertion targetcount = sourcecount then it should pass or it needs to fail. I m quite new with ruby.